# if class B implements interface C, and class A extends B, does class A need to implement C too?

Tags: typescript, inheritance, extends, implements

I was reviewing some code and stumbled upon this:

```
export class A extends B implements C {
  ...
}
```

And then this other class

```
export abstract class B implements C {
  ...
}
```

Then I thought, if class A extends B, and B already implements interface C (as shown below), is it necessary for A to implement C too?

I hope I made myself clear and is not too complicated.

Thanks!

Comment: No, it is not necessary.

Comment: `export` is not a valid modifier for Java classes. Besides that, when `A` extends `B` it implicitly implements `C`.

Comment: No, it will implicitly implements `C` class because it's in the super-class `B`.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to implement `C` when `B` is extended and it implements `C`. It's implicitly implemented when `A` extends `B`.

Though there's nothing wrong with doing it either (it's not going to crash the program)

---

Also, `export` is not a valid keyword in Java. The closest I get in terms of usage is related to TypeScript. You're probably looking for `public` instead

Comment: Okay, I got confused while making the question, it's indeed typescript, I'll edit it now, and thanks! that was the answer I was looking for :D

Answer (score 1):

If `class A extends B` and `class B implements C`, class `A` implements interface `C`, and doesn't have to declare `implements C` explicitly.

However, adding such `implements C` is a common practice in JDK classes.

For example:

```
class ArrayList<E> extends AbstractList<E> implements List<E>
```

may seem redundant, since `AbstractList` already implements `List`:

```
class AbstractList<E> extends AbstractCollection<E> implements List<E>
```

However, it is useful for the users of the `ArrayList` class to immediately see that it implements the `List` interface, without having to look into the `AbstractList` class (which is an implementation detail).

Answer (score 0):

> if class B implements class C, and class A extends B, does class A
>   need to implement C too?

First of all, a `class` can never **implement** a different `class`. They **extend** it. A `class` can only **implement** `interface`s

Now, whatever you implements and/or extends, `class` or `interface` became part of same hierarchy.

When class `B` implementes `C` interface

```
abstract class B implements C
```

Then, you don't need to implement again to class `A` as you have already extended class `B` and class `B` implements `C`

```
class A extends B
```

Comment: @nbokmans What are you talking man. Please read my answer carfully.

Comment: *First of all* - so where is the other part of your answer ?

Comment: @Rafalon updating mate :P

Comment: @Rafalon it received about 3 edits in a few minutes, it was posted before it was finished

Comment: Yeah, I got it a little bit wrong, C is indeed an interface, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

First, @nbokmans is right. `export` is not a Java keyword.

> Then I thought, if class A extends B, and B already implements C (as
>   shown below), is it necessary for A to implement C too?

It is not necessary as the class inheritance is transitive in Java.

[**Chapter 8. Classes. 8.1.4. Superclasses and Subclasses**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.4)

> The subclass relationship is the transitive closure of the direct
>   subclass relationship. A class A is a subclass of class C if either of
>   the following is true:
>
> - A is the direct subclass of C
> - There exists a class B such that A is a subclass of B, and B is a
>     subclass of C, applying this definition recursively.

Now make it explicit it :

```
class A extends B implements C {
```

makes sense if `A` makes part of an API that is used by other applications.
It documents explicitly `C` as an interface that `A` implements.

Comment: Thought `C` was an interface, or do I misunderstand your last two words ?

Comment: @Rafalon You are right. It is confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Let's Interface is being defined as following

```
interface C {
    public void fun();
}
```

As class B implements interface C, In class B it's mandatory to implement method fun(). But since the class is being defined as the abstract then implementation of method fun() can be skipped as child class can provide the implementation.

```
abstract class B implements C {


}
```

Now as class A extends B, so it has already implemented interface C too by general inheritance rule. So it's not required explicitly that A will implement C interface but yes syntactically it's perfectly valid.

```
class A extends B {

    public void fun() {

    }
}
```